# divisors of $p^4+1$ of the form $kp+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In group theory the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite group $G$, is of the form $kp+1$.

So it is interesting to discuss about the divisors of  this form. As I checked it seems that for an odd prime $p$, there is not any divisor $a$ of $p^4+1$, where $1<a<p^4+1$ and $a=kp+1$, for some $k>0$.
Could you help me about this question? If it is true how we can prove it?

Also when I checked the same fact for $p^8+1$, we get many counterexamples. What is the difference between $4$ and $8$?

Comment: You checked for $p^4+1$ until which bound?

Comment: for primes $p$ less than 20000 by GAP

Comment: Now YCor has settled this, of course. Note, however, that we have the easy factorization $p^{4}+1 = (p^{2} - \sqrt{2}p +1)(p^{2}+\sqrt{2}p +1)$ in the Euclidean ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (both factors clearly congruent to $1$ (mod $p$), though $p$ need not be prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$). This is not especially relevant to counting Sylow $p$-subgroups in groups of course!

Comment: Dear Professor Robinson, Thanks for your kind answers for all questions in group theory and also for my previous questions. I study some groups of orders for example as $p^i(p^4+1)$ and also $p^i(p^8+1)$ and I want to find the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: Yes, groups of order $p^{i}(p^{4}+1)$ are interesting by virtue of the answer to the question.

Comment: Indeed, it implies that a group $G$ of order $p^i(p^4+1)$ has characteristic subgroups $N\subset M$ such that $G/M$ and $N$ are $p$-groups, and $M/N$ has order $p^4+1$.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's none indeed.

**Lemma**: if $1<m<n$ are coprime integers then $mn+1$ does not divide $n^4+1$.

First observe that for any $m,n$, of $mn+1$ divides $n^4+1$, then it divides $n^4m^4+m^4=((nm)^4-1)+1+m^4$, and since $mn+1$ clearly divides $((nm)^4-1)$, we deduce that it also divides $1+m^4$.

To prove the lemma, assume the contrary. As we have just seen, $mn+1$ divides $m^4+1$ as well. Write $(m^4+1)/(mn+1)=k$, and $k=(\ell m+r)$ with $0\le r\le m-1$. Then $m^4+1=(\ell m+r)((mn+1)=mN'+r$, so $r=1$. So $(\ell m+1)$ divides $m^4+1$. Then $m$ and $\ell$ are coprime: indeed, we have $(m\ell +1)(mn+1)=m^4+1$, so $\ell(mn+1)-m^3=-n$. If a prime $p$ were dividing both $m$ and $\ell$ then it would also divide $n$, contradicting that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, so $m$ and $\ell$ are indeed coprime. We have $\ell<n$ because otherwise
$$m^4+1=(mn+1)(m\ell+1)\ge (mn+1)^2> (m^2+1)^2>m^4+1.$$ So we found a new pair $(m,\ell)$ with $\max(m,\ell)<n$, with $m\ell+1$ dividing both $m^4+1$ and $\ell^4+1$. So, assuming that $n$ is minimal, we're done unless $\ell=1$. This happens if $m+1$ divides $m^4+1$, and since $m+1$ divides $m^4-1$ as well, if this occurs then $m+1=2$, contradicting $m>1$.

(Note: without the coprime assumption the conclusion fails, as $(m,n)=(m,m^3)$ for $m\ge 2$, e.g. $(m,n)=(2,8)$, satisfies $mn+1|n^4+1$.)

**Proposition** If $p$ is prime then $p^4+1$ has no divisor of the form $kp+1$ except $1$ and $p^4+1$.

Proof: write $p^4+1=(kp+1)(k'p+\ell)$ with $0\le\ell\le p-1$; then $\ell=1$. So exchanging $k$ and $k'$ if necessary we can suppose $k\le k'$. 
If by contradiction $k$ is divisible by $p$ then $k'\ge k\ge p$, so $p^4+1\ge (p^2+1)^2>p^4+1$, contradiction. So $k$ and $p$ are coprime, and the lemma yields a contradiction.

Comment: The proof is very nice, thanks YCor.

Comment: Where do you use primality of $p$? For $p$ composite $p=4096$ divisors are: 65537, 4294901761

Comment: when we get that any integer less than $p$ is coprime with respect to it (in the last line of the proof).

Comment: A great example of Vieta jumping!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping [This technique has been burned into my brain since 1988, when I failed to solve an IMO problem requiring this trick.]

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the problem is in fact closely related to IMO 1988 Q6, since if $kp+1$ divides $p^4+1$, then it also divides $k^2+p^2$.

Comment: In the last bit of the proof of the lemma, it looks like it should be $m+1=2$ rather than $m=2$.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: thanks, I had forgotten the computation of $2-1$ :) (Now edited: I could remove a useless line from the proof then).

Comment: @TerryTao How does $kp+1 \mid p^4+1$ imply $kp+1 \mid k^2+p^2$? Can you please shed some light? I am aware of the IMO 1988 problem. Does this follow by applying that Vieta Jumping technique. I am unable to see this instantly

Comment: @crskhr If it divides $p^4+1$ then it also divides $p^4+1-(kp+1)=p(p^3-k)$. Since $kp+1$ is coprime to $p$ this implies $kp+1$ divides $p^3-k$, hence divides $kp^3-k^2$. Hence it divides $-(kp^3-k^2)+p^2(kp+1)=k^2+p^2$.

Comment: @YCor Whoaaa!!! Thanks for the kind help. Extremely tricky answer :)

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to draw your attention to https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4926/2021-moderator-election-suggestions-for-nominees/4938#4938

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be prime. Assume that $q \mid p^4+1$, where $q = ap+1$ for some
$a \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $(p^4+1)/q \equiv 1 \!\! \mod p$, hence
$p^4+1 = (ap+1)(bp+1)$ for some $b \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now we have $p^4 = abp^2+(a+b)p$, respectively, $p^3-abp-a-b = 0$. Therefore, effectively
we are looking for solutions to the diophantine equation $x^3-xyz-y-z=0$ in positive
$x$, $y$, $z$, and prime $x$.

When allowing negative (or zero) $x, y, z$, we would get a lot of solutions,
and for positive $x, y, z \leq 1000$, we still find (up to switching of $y$ and $z$)
$$
  (x,y,z) \in \{(8,30,2),(27,240,3),(30,112,8),(112,418,30)\}.
$$
I don't know whether there is a solution with prime $x$ as required --
however we have a diophantine equation of total degree $3$ in $3$ variables,
and such are (at least potentially) hard.